# Expo video plays in different time position on long press

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

I want to make this feature with React Native Expo-AV Video component.
When user long press on video component, video will play 1 second at 4 different time positions like in xvideos' videos.
Or do they use gif in video's poster?

Comment: Have you found a solution ?